# Did Soviet cars have seatbelts or laws enforcing them?

Tags: soviet-union, law, automobiles

I know in America, the seatbelt has a history involving legislation and Ralph Nader, and didn't really exist before the 1960's.

What about in the Soviet Union? Did they go through a similar process? When, if ever, was the seatbelt implemented in Soviet cars, and were there laws enforcing their use?

Comment: Can't imagine having to get out of a Lada often enough to smack the engine with a heavy implement (hammer, monkey wrench, etc) while constantly buckling and unbuckling a seatbelt... :)

Answer (score 16):

The production of safety belts in Soviet Union was started in Estonian SSR by NPO Norma which still exists.

According to [AS Norma website](http://www.norma.ee/index.php?lang=eng):

> Our connections with the international automotive industry were established **in 1973**, the year in which Norma started producing safety belts for cars.

The obligation of using safety belts (if a car is equipped with them) was introduced in the Amendments to Traffic Regulation Orders which came into force on **1st April 1975**.

Here is [March 1975 issue](http://www.zr.ru/archive/zr/1975/03/novoie-v-pravilakh-dorozhnogho-dvizhieniia) of Soviet magazine "*За рулём*" (At the wheel) which discusses new regulations.

BTW. Driving an old car without safety belts equipped is legal even nowadays.

Comment: `BTW. Driving an old car without safety belts equipped is legal even nowadays.` Do you mean in USA, or Russia? Or maybe both?

Comment: @DrZ214 I mean in Russia. Don't know anything about USA.

Answer (score 5):

The seat belts appeared in the Soviet Union in the 1970s, first without enforcing laws, and shortly after the laws were introduced. I do not remember the year when this happened but some time in the late 1970s or early 80s.

Comment: Thanks, you sound like someone who lived in the region, which is a great source for answers. Can I interest you in supporting the Soviet Union Stackexchange site proposal? http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97056/soviet-union

Comment: @DrZ214: Yes, I lived in the Soviet Union from the late 50s until its break. But why is a separate SE needed for SU? What is wrong with this History SE?

Comment: Nothing is necessarily wrong with History.SE. I think the Soviet Union is big enough to warrant it's own SE site. (Big not just land, but in history, culture, technology, and it's own sphere). There are other SE sites it might overlap with, such as Politics.SE. There are plenty of current SE sites that overlap each other, such as Engineering.SE with Physics.SE., and there is even an Elecrical Engineering SE that's a subset. So I see no reason why there can't be a subset in history if it's big enough.

Comment: The question is not how big was SU but how many people are interested in such a separate SE. BTW I registered and can answer some questions there, but cannot figure what to click to answer.

Comment: For now you should just vote there and post your own example questions that you think are good. You can use comments to answer if you really want. There's a 500-character limit, but u can always post multiple comments. Personally, I think it's a dumb restriction on Proposal SE sites. Letting us answer in the normal way can only increase user participation. But the setup means you have to use comments. Don't wory, tho, I will be using the same 5 questions here on History.SE, because I want answers and because I want to advertise SU.SE.